# Minor bugs with the Review

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review, low-quality-posts

1. **Low Quality Posts & Suggested Edits** - 500 reviews limit counts "Not Sure", so it says I reviewed 500 posts, but I've actually reviewed 490 (10 skipped). 
   It's totally vice versa with suggested edits: if I've skipped 3 edits, and reviewed another 50, it shows that I've reviewed 53. [Proof here](http://prntscr.com/d4h03)
2. **Low Quality Posts** - After skipping a post, there's no a timer that doesn't allow reviewing for 2 seconds - I can review it immediately.

Not such a great bugs, but they're still bugs :)

Comment: You should really post these two bug reports separately. I recommend editing to remove the second one, change the title to describe the first one, and make a new post for the second one. Then they can be answered, voted on, tracked, and assigned a status, separately. Also, what do you mean by "totally vice versa" in the first one? It seems like the two cases you're describing in the first "bug" are exactly analogous--even when you click Not Sure, it's counted as a review.

Comment: The first issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue was fixed awhile ago, the second issue should be rolled out in production right now.

Thanks for the report!